# KVM Network Bridge to assign Static IP

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I installed Ubuntu server 14.04. and assigned static IP to it... then installed KVM and Virtual machine manager... then created a test virtual machine and it worked fine also with local IP address over NAT.

I have two LAN Card and only one is connected to internet.

What i want is configuration to bridge em2 to guest machines. So, that static ip address work also for guest machines. Right now if i assing static ip to guest machine there is no connectivity.

My ifconfig details is:

```
ifconfig -a

em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:4d:96:aa  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  
          Memory:f7100000-f717ffff  

em2       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:4d:96:ab  
          inet addr:68.168.105.130  Bcast:68.168.105.255  Mask:255.255.255.0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::ec4:7aff:fe4d:96ab/64 Scope:Link  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:3717 errors:0 dropped:10 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:373 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
          RX bytes:269655 (269.6 KB)  TX bytes:239608 (239.6 KB)  
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7200000-f7220000  

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0  
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host  
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1  
          RX packets:123 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:123 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0  
          RX bytes:8881 (8.8 KB)  TX bytes:8881 (8.8 KB)  

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:23:1c:65  
          inet addr:192.168.100.1  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0  
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  

virbr0-nic Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:23:1c:65  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500  
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

and /etc/network/interfaces details is:

```
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  


auto em2  
iface em2 inet static  
        address 68.168.105.130  
       netmask 255.255.255.0  
       network 68.168.105.0  
       broadcast 68.168.105.255  
       gateway 68.168.105.1  
       # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed  
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8  
        dns-search dedicated.codero.net
```

Comment: Are you saying you have multiple public static IP addresses (for example 68.168.105.129), and you want to use additional ones on your quest VM's, bridged via em2?

Comment: Yes, this is dedicated server and i want to assign remaining 3 extra IP to different guest OS..  IP Pool i have is 68.168.105.101-68.168.105.103 and only lan card that is online is em2 already assigned static ip

Comment: O.K. it is just so unusual, is why I wanted to check. I posted an answer that should work.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Step 1: Create the bridge

You probably have `bridge-utils` installed already, but in case you don't:

```
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
```

In the host and as root, edit `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 68.168.105.130
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 68.168.105.0
broadcast 68.168.105.255
gateway 68.168.105.1
# dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
dns-search dedicated.codero.net 
bridge_ports em2
bridge_fd 9
bridge_hello 2
bridge_maxage 12
bridge_stp off
```

Now you can either re-boot or:

```
sudo ifup br0
```

[Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#bridging)

### Step 2: Modify your VM definition to use the bridge

Note: There is probably a way to do this step using `virt-manager`, however I do not use it and do not know how.

Use `virsh edit` and change your interface definition lines to use bridging instead of what is currently being used. Here is an example from one of my VMs. Before:

```xml
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:0d:ed:95'/>
  <source network='default'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

after:

```xml
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:0d:ed:95'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

### Step 3: Specify the static IP address in the guest VM

Now, while running the guest VM, which might have network issues for the moment, edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the static definition for the interface name. For example, and guessing a little for your setup:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 68.168.105.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 68.168.105.0
broadcast 68.168.105.255
gateway 68.168.105.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
dns-search dedicated.codero.net
```

#### Notes:

The default editor used by `virsh edit` is as defined by the `$EDITOR` environment variable, or `vi` if it does not exist. add `export EDITOR="/bin/nano"` to your `~/.bashrc` file to set, for example, nano as your default editor.

You MUST use `virsh edit` do **not** edit the XML file directly, as `virsh edit` will do a bunch of checks upon save and exit. From any directory, and for example, do:

```
virsh edit desk_tt
```

Comment: As far as I know virt-manager is regarded as a good tool, I just don't use it. A backup solution is a different question, and I don't know anyhow. I just use rsync to another computer. I spent considerable time on my answer. If it worked for you, please accept it.

Comment: are you suggesting to *replace* the existing entry `em2` (presumably the hardware interface) with the entry for `br0` in `etc/network/interfaces`? Or is the `br0` entry added?

Comment: @Mausy5043: The existing entry is replaced. Notice that em2 is still referenced via the `bridge_ports` directive.

Comment: Thanks. Now http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/bridge-utils-interfaces.5.html starts to make sense. ;-)

Comment: @CodeMed : Sorry, I don't have anything to add over what I said in my answer here. It should not be such a difficult thing as all you seem to be having to go through.

Comment: Well done.  This deserves many more upvotes.  One thing that a colleague clarified is that all your guests can share the single br0.  You might add that.