# Setting up bridged networking with KVM

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to install KVM. I've done the installation and I'm now following the second part of the [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking) to get bridged networking to work. However, I'm stuck at the part where I need to modify the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

(Note: I don't have X installed.)

I'm on Ubuntu Server 15.04:

```
$ uname -a
Linux boson 3.19.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:31:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

:

```
$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:11098 (11.0 KB)  TX bytes:11098 (11.0 KB)

p17p1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:5f:f4:ea:0e:28
          inet addr:10.0.1.220  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::be5f:f4ff:feea:e28/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:173566 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:219213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:18152992 (18.1 MB)  TX bytes:208778324 (208.7 MB)
          Interrupt:16

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:82:25:dd
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

The file currently looks like this:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto p17p1
iface p17p1 inet dhcp

#auto virbr0
#iface virbr0 inet dhcp
#        bridge_ports p17p1
#        bridge_stp off
#        bridge_fd 0
#        bridge_maxwait 0
```

If I uncomment those last lines and do `systemctl restart networking` the network connection on `p17p1` is lost. `ifconfig` then shows that both `p17p1` and `virbr0` have the same IP-address.

Should I use the static settings instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to use static settings instead.
Also, I see that you have already found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638162/kvm-network-bridge-to-assign-static-ip)

For a dynamic IP address solution, you should set up a real bridge and use it. Your interfaces file should become:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
   bridge_ports p17p1
   bridge_fd 9
   bridge_hello 2
   bridge_maxage 12
   bridge_stp off
```

Note: I got some of the settings from the [Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#bridging)

Comment: I think I got confused with the example on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking .  Where they list *both* the hardware `eth0` *as well as* the `br0` bridge.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later this week and let you know.  This question (well the answer to it actually) was also helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/638162/kvm-network-bridge-to-assign-static-ip . Although not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: These settings seem to work. Moving forward with setting things up. Thanks!