# NAT port forwarding using iptable doesn't work

Tags: ssh, iptables, port-forwarding, nat, virt-manager

I have a server with `Ubuntu Server` and a `Xubuntu` virtual machine on it, virtualization software is `virt-manager`.

```
Ubuntu Server IP: 172.16.63.140
Xubuntu Virtual Machine IP: 192.168.122.4
```

I can do

```
ssh 172.16.63.140
```

to connect to `Ubuntu Server`, and from this ssh shell i can do

```
ssh 192.168.122.4
```

to connect to the `Xubuntu Virtual Machine`.

Using iptables i want to forward ssh port to make virtual machine visible from the outside, these are the commands i use:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i em1 --dport 22222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.4:22
sudo /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.122.4 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

this is the output of iptables:

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.122.4        tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
user@hostname:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:22222 to:192.168.122.4:22

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

but if i do:

```
ssh -p 22222 172.16.63.140
```

this is the content of `/etc/network/interfaces` on host

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em1
#iface em1 inet dhcp

#MICHELE MODIFIED: delete from here
iface em1 inet static
    address 172.16.63.140
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 172.16.63.0
    broadcast 172.16.63.255
    gateway 172.16.63.254
```

this is the content of `/etc/network/interfaces` on guest

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

this is the content of /etc/libvirt/qemu/UbuntuSynth.xml

```
<!--
WARNING: THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED FILE. CHANGES TO IT ARE LIKELY TO BE
OVERWRITTEN AND LOST. Changes to this xml configuration should be made using:
  virsh edit UbuntuSynth
or other application using the libvirt API.
-->

<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>UbuntuSynth</name>
  <uuid>21851d31-25f2-940b-8cff-afa09e329713</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-trusty'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/UbuntuSynth.img'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:75:4c:d3'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

host machine `ifconfig`

```
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:1f:af:ef:1b:b5  
          inet addr:172.16.63.140  Bcast:172.16.63.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f21f:afff:feef:1bb5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28474137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65644719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2701543645 (2.7 GB)  TX bytes:86462963020 (86.4 GB)
          Memory:da500000-da600000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12327288 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12327288 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2986574536 (2.9 GB)  TX bytes:2986574536 (2.9 GB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:75:4c:d3  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15817438 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28427336 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:82982143933 (82.9 GB)  TX bytes:2706857124 (2.7 GB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:8e:0b:d3  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe8e:bd3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12504257 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25522667 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:81619900128 (81.6 GB)  TX bytes:1884322484 (1.8 GB)

vnet1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:75:4c:d3  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe75:4cd3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3313181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3248438 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:1583687937 (1.5 GB)  TX bytes:842952463 (842.9 MB)
```

guest machine `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:75:4c:d3  
          inet addr:192.168.122.4  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe75:4cd3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3163707 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3313229 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:794261483 (794.2 MB)  TX bytes:1583695154 (1.5 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10588809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10588809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3603005625 (3.6 GB)  TX bytes:3603005625 (3.6 GB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

from my laptop the connection will return with timeout error, where is the problem?

Comment: What's the output of sysctl -a | grep forwarding ?

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a return path in your iptables rules set. You need:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o em1 -j SNAT --to 172.16.63.140
```

You also need to make sure forwarding is enabled . Example:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Comment: just tried but doesn't work

Comment: We are going to need more information. While it looks as though you are using the default stuff (i.e. 192.168.122.X and maybe virbr0), there are normally some related iptables rules that I don't see. Please add to your question the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` for both the host and the quest. also add the network interface section of the `/etc/libvirt/qemu/???.xml` definition file.

Comment: If you are interested, it might make sense to bridge em1 and have your guest on the 172.16.63.X sub-net. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/641903/setting-up-bridged-networking-with-kvm) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/638162/kvm-network-bridge-to-assign-static-ip).

Comment: i have added the requested information

Comment: sorry, also need the output from `ifconfig` from both the host and the quest.

Comment: added ifcongif for both machine