# MaaS server with local kvm - How to bridge to dhcp interface

Tags: networking, maas, dhcp, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I have a MaaS server, it has two network interfaces. One external eth0, and one for the internal network eth1(Nodes network). eth1 is where the DNS and dhcp server managed interface. I want a mix of physical servers, and one KVM VM run on the MaaS server. I manage to create VM's to PXE Boot, and created a bridge br01 bridged with the eth1 interface.

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

And that bridge is associated with the VM's network.

Now this works if created on an external server connected to the eth1 network(tried earlier as proof of concept).

But what I want is to move this KVM setup over to the MaaS Server itself(to free up a physical server as Node), and then this network configuration is not working.

The network part of the VM's xml file:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:3c:a5:18'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

I created the VM using:

```
sudo virt-install --name=bootstrap-juju --ram=2048 --vcpus=1 
--disk path=/var/kvm/images/bootstrap-juju.qcow2,bus=virtio,size=20 
--pxe --graphics=vnc --hvm --network bridge=br0,model=virtio 
--os-variant=ubuntuprecise
```

It seems that there is a problem with the bridge, when I `sudo ifup br0` I get:

```
DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xcb27ff35)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
```

So it seems the bridge is not getting DHCP address from the internal dhcp server.

Does anyone have any pointers here?

Comment: Please post the interface section of your xml definition file, `/etc/libvirt/qemu/server_name.xml`. The interface should be defined as type=bridge and be set to using br0 as the source bridge. see also [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/638162/kvm-network-bridge-to-assign-static-ip) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/641903/setting-up-bridged-networking-with-kvm/642009).

Comment: Updated my question with more info. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Yes, I saw, but everything looks O.K. so I am stumped. The only other things I can think to look at are the guest `/etc/network.interfaces` file and the output from `ifconfig` on the guest.

Comment: I meant to write `/etc/network/interfaces` yesterday. Perhaps post both files for both the host and the guest. your `sudo ifup br0` command was done on the host right? On my host I get `ifup: interface br0 already configured`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had a few problems. My `eth1` was still defined as static in my `/etc/network/interfaces`. I had to remove it, and change my `br0` with matching static settings. Then on the `Cluster master` in MaaS, change the Managed DHCP-DNS interface from `eth1` to `br0`.

Hope this helps someone.